# Wet fingers / dry fingers completing a small DC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits

I am playing with a toy DC circuit. It has 2 AA batteries, 1 small speaker, and two cables one on each end. The two cables can be attached to complete a circuit and the speaker plays a sound.

Given this setup, I can of course dip the ends of both cables in a bowl of water, without them directly touching each other, it will complete a circuit as well. You get the drift.

Now, if I just hold the ends of both wires, one in each hand, then it is NOT completing a circuit...
But, if I make my fingers wet and then hold the ends of the wires with wet fingers (both cables not touching, as I am holding one end in each hand), then magically the circuit completes!

Can someone please explain why the circuit is NOT completed in the first case, but it is in the second case? The only difference is wet fingers! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your circuit is probably a sensitive current detector, and can sense when your skin is capable of conducting even a tiny trickle of current. Now the skin on your fingers has salt in and on it, and when your skin gets wet, the salt dissolves and the top layer of the skin becomes a pretty good conductor- much better than when your skin is dry. That trips the circuit and sets off the alarm.

Comment: Based on some key words you mentioned.. I searched again, and found this link.. which made it more clear.. Thanks
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67539/why-does-wet-skin-offer-less-resistance